# What "boundary conditions" can make a rectangle "look" like a circle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, approximation, circles, conformal-geometry

I posted the question below in `Stackoverflow` but then realized that it perhaps would find a better audience here.

I am solving a fourth order non-linear partial differential equation
in time and space `(t, x)` on a square domain with periodic or free
boundary conditions with MATHEMATICA.

**Without** using conformal mapping, what boundary conditions at the edge
or corner could I use to make the square domain "seem" like a circular
domain for my non-linear partial differential equation which is
cartesian?

The options I would **not** like to use are:

- Conformal mapping
- changing my equation to polar/cylindrical coordinates?

This is something I am pursuing purely out of interest just in case
someone screams bloody murder if misconstrued as a homework problem!
 `:P`

Edit:

If I have a result from solving a PDE in cartesian coordinates, how do I transfer these results or view them in polar coordinates?

Comment: Your question is quite imprecise; I don't understand what you mean for a square to "look" or "seem" like a circle. It might help if you explained what you find unsatisfactory about conformal mapping and polar coordinates.

Comment: @RahulNarain If I have results of a PDE in cartesian coordinates, how do I transfer them to polar coordinates?